# GCE Instances - edit start-up script from inside a script

Tags: google-compute-engine

I use a startup-script (via metaData) on my initiated instances and I want it to "self destruct" after it starts. but i see, to have no permissions to change it. what could i do? (besides setting it via setMetadata)

thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to shut down the instance after the startup script runs? Or simply remove the startup script once it has run once?

Comment: for this question i only want to remove it. but actually i'd also like to shut it down :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, your Google Compute Engine VM instance needs to have the right scope which provides read-write access to the Google Compute Engine API.

- If you use `gcloud` to create your instances, to set the right scope, do this:

  ```
  gcloud compute instances create [...] --scopes compute-rw
  ```

  The full list of scopes for `gcloud` is documented in the [`gcloud` help page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create).
- If you are using Google Developers Console, check the appropriate box on the instance creation page to add the GCE read-write scope.

  First, click on the "Management, disk, networking, access & security options" option to expand it, and then click on the tab "Access & security" to find the check boxes..
- If you are writing code using [Google Client API and authorizing via OAuth2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization), you'll need to use the full URL of the GCE read-write scope:

  ```
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
  ```

Once you do this, given that `gcloud` is pre-installed on all standard GCE VM images, your startup script can just use the appropriate command, e.g., [`gcloud compute instances delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete).